# Which autolisp / autocad version to use for maximum compatibility with existing deployments?

Tags: autocad, autolisp

I'm about to dive into autolisp and am wondering how to write code that is compatible with as many different versions of autocad as possible, obviously including the current one but also stretching back ideally as far as 2000.

Autodesk have an FAQ on this http://usa.autodesk.com/adsk/servlet/item?siteID=123112&id=770225 but don't mention anything before 2009.

Which version of (i) autocad and (ii) the autolisp compiler should I work with?  Also, is this the same thing as visual lisp?

Comment: Why LISP? Do you have experience with it, or any other languages? There are APIs for .NET and C++ (called ObjectARX), in case you didn't know.

Comment: Please correct me if I'm wrong, but it sounds to me like lisp is used as the internal scripting language for autocad, so provided it supports the functionailiy I need, it will be easier to develop for that in spite of my existing C++ experience.  All I need to do is read designs out of autocad, send them to a dll I have written already, and write the results back into the drawing.

Comment: @Bob You're on the right track. ARX is much more involved than LISP. Unless you need the performance (LISP is much slower) then, for simple tasks, LISP is a good idea and much simpler to implement. Also much more version compatibility. LISP is not going anywhere soon. Also, it _may_ run in AutoCAD clones like IntelliCAD. For a lot of great AutoLISP tips & solutions, see theswamp.org and the Autodesk forums.

The .NET API is next on the degree of difficulty and perfomance scales, ignoring the now-defunct VBA.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AutoLisp is interpreted, not compiled, so there are no different compilers to choose from (although there is an option to compile them to .fas files but most of the time you wouldn't bother).

VisualLisp is an extension to the AutoLisp language which allows you to access the object model in the same way as you would if using VBA, just from AutoLisp. If you use built-in functions that starts with vl- or vla- then you're already using VisualLisp.

Compatibility is mostly a matter of only using features which work the same across all versions.

This doesn't always go to plan however, and you may have to create some version-specific files which you load at the end and which redefine some functions to work with that specific version (you can easily tell which version of AutoCAD the lisp is being loaded into).

Comment: +1 I didn't realise the compilation was optional, that helps!

Comment: Compiling to .fas is really just for protecting your source code. It's because AutoLisp is interpreted that makes development so quick: you just type some code into vlide, select it and run it. All the variables (including function definitions) stay in that drawing session so you can incrementally develop your functionality very quickly...

Comment: Most problems you will have will be in trying to access API functions which don't exist, or which have changed. There are a few forums you can glean this info from and ask questions on. Try theswamp.org, Autodesk's forums and AUGI forums

Answer (score 2):

I'd disagree with first poster.  You want to make sure everything works with brand new versions, then tweak it for older.  Most companies who use Autocad and survived the recession did so because they keep up.

Comment: FYI, "first poster" is prone to misunderstanding since the ordering of posts is not static. By default, ordering of posts is by votes (posts with the same votes are randomly ordered).

Comment: Would a sensible approach be to get hold of both 2000 and the latest one, if I can write code that works in both of those it's likely to work in everything between..?

Comment: PS I'm writing code for government bodies here, heck knows what version they're on!

Comment: Ask them. They will have submission specifications somewhere which will state what version of AutoCAD the DWGs need to be in. That will give you an idea but your best bet is to contact CAD managers in the relevant government departments and ask them what they have.

Answer (score 1):

Older is better in your case. You should work with the 2000 version. But I'm not sure if it can work on modern OS.

Answer (score 1):

The good news is that the programs I have written in AutoLISP since 1994 mostly are still chugging along with very few changes.  Here are some things you might consider:

1. Because AutoCAD is expensive, there is a thriving ecosystem of AutoCAD clones like Carlson IntelliCAD, BricsCAD, and ProgeCAD.  All of the ones I mentioned run AutoLISP, but sometimes with slight quirks, and I don't think they run the Visual LISP extensions.  Most of my AutoCAD AutoLISP programs work with very little tweaking in Intellicad/BricsCAD.
2. I personally try at the moment to develop for v2010+.  But I have run into people still using v2004.  The only real difference from 2004 to now (in AutoLISP) is a few new kinds of objects (like mleaders) and settings that you would want to stay away from if you want to be compatible with the older versions.
3. There are very active forums like TheSwamp and the Autodesk forums where you can have really good discussions and get good help with AutoLISP programming questions.